# viewDidLoad() Getting Called Before prepareForSegue() Finishes: Swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am have a `ContainerVC` which holds a variable `controllerToLoad`. By Default it is "MainVC" however when clicking on a menu item, I wish to present the `ContainerVC`but instead of loading `MainVC`, I wish to load `SecondVC`. 
I load the MainVC in the ViewDidLoad method of my ContainerVC by doing the following:

```
if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(controllerToLoad) {
    self.mainViewController = controller
}
```

I thought the best way to do this is by segue, so I call the following lines of code:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MenuSegue", sender: self)
```

Then in my `prepareForSegue` I do the following:

```
if (segue.identifier == "MenuSegue"){
   let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ContainerViewController
   secondViewController.controllerToLoad = "SecondVC"
}
```

For some reason, when calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` it automatically loads the `ContainerVC` and starts to sets `self.mainViewController` to "MainVC" instead of waiting for `prepareForSegue` to run. I don't know why its not waiting for `prepareForSegue` to finish.

I tested this by adding bunch of print statements. right before `self.performSegueWithIdentifier` and before `secondViewController.controllerToLoad = "SecondVC"` and in `ViewDidLoad` of my `ContainerVC`. After adding the print statements I realized that in fact as soon as `performSegueWithIdentifier` is called, right after it calls `ViewDidLoad` of `ContainerVC` then performs

`let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ContainerViewController
   secondViewController.controllerToLoad = "SecondVC"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct and to be expected behaviour. In `prepareForSegue` you can access the `destinationViewController` and its properties, including UIView elements, so logically the view must have already been loaded. Hence, `viewDidLoad` will have been called.

You could use another method, such as `viewWillAppear`, which executes after `prepareForSegue` but it seems that a different approach would be better. Perhaps a method on your container view controller that told it to load and present a new VC.

Comment: Yea, you were right. I took my ContainerVC code and put it into a method which sets the self.mainViewController to a variable I pass. Great hint!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't need to do both these things. You instantiate mainController, but when you perfromSegue MainSegue there is second instance of mainController created and you have wrong view life cycle events method calls sequence. you either must push mainController by pushViewController:animated or don't create it at all.